# WCF RESTful call with unexpected header error

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

With a C# client & server doing RESTful calls through WCF, the client trace exposes this error:

"Envelope Version 'EnvelopeNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none)' does not support adding Message Headers."

The full stack trace is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Envelope Version 'EnvelopeNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none)' does not support adding Message Headers.

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeaders.ValidateHeaderKind(HeaderKind headerKind)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeaders.GetHeaderKind(MessageHeaderInfo headerInfo)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeaders.Insert(Int32 headerIndex, MessageHeader header)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeaders.Add(MessageHeader header)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.DiagosticsMessage.AddHeader(String scheme, Boolean enableHttpHeaderUsage, Message message, Byte[] networkBuffer)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.EnabledClientEventSink.BeforeSendMessage(Int32 eventingLevel, Message request, IClientChannel channel, ClientRuntime runtime, Boolean fCallback, Boolean fSupportAsmx)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.StubClientEventSink.System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest(Message&amp; request, IClientChannel channel)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableClientRuntime.BeforeSendRequest(ProxyRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.PrepareCall(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Boolean oneway, ProxyRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
at Fact.Apprentice.WorkflowServer.IWorkflowEngineBase.Dequeue(Int32 wfid, Int32 mqid)
at Fact.Apprentice.WorkflowTools.WorkflowProxyManager.ProcessCallback(Object state, Boolean timedOut)
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.WaitOrTimerCallback_Context(Object state, Boolean timedOut)
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.WaitOrTimerCallback_Context_t(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Object state, Boolean timedOut)
```

To my knowledge I'm not adding any headers.  It appears some kind of .NET diagnostic process is adding its own.

My understanding also is that in the past one did not use MessageHeaders.Add for REST based header manipulation.  Is this a bug/misconfiguration in the WCF diagnostic area?  Where should I look to fix this problem?

Extra:  Interestingly, the WCF REST calls do work, even with this error.  However, eventually a timeout brings the whole thing down.  Can't say whether the timeout is related to this or not though.

Comment: Fact.Apprentice stuff is my own code.  IWorkflowEngineBase.Dequeue represents the client proxy for my WCF service.  I will check the system log for threading exceptions, good idea

Comment: Oh also IWorkflowEngineBase I assure you is an interface.  I think the autogenerated proxy magic is showing through there.